# Simple slopes: seq.default(to = nrow(grid)) : 'to' must be of length 1

Tags: r

I am trying to create some simple slopes using the following code:

```
model <- lm(EE ~ HO4 + A + interaction,  data = MyData)
> Coefficients:
    (Intercept)              HO4         AFactor1         AFactor2         AFactor3         AFactor4  
         4.6190          -0.2876          -1.9633          -1.4149          -1.8414          -1.6004  
       AFactor5  interactionPlot  
        -1.7431          -0.1724
```

My simple model seems to be working, as the output shows.
So what I try to do is inserting my 3 variables I use for my moderation analysis.
I do know, that those 3 variables and the interaction (ZHO4 * ZA) output a significant moderation.
After creating a simple model I try to run the simple slopes function, resulting in this error:

```
library("reghelper")
simple_slopes(model)
> Error in seq.default(to = nrow(grid)) : 'to' must be of length 1
```

EE = Dependent Variable

HO4 = Independent Variable

A = Moderator

Z = standardized

How can I get it to work?
Or are there any other options to output simple slopes?